# Table view section headers not updating

Tags: uitableview, header, nsfetchedresultscontroller

ViewA lists data grouped by section, and when you select a row you go to ViewB. After potentially editing several fields, you use the back button to go back to ViewA.  If the attribute used as the section header is edited in ViewB, the new value doesn't show up in ViewA unless you back out of it and go back into it.

The only way I can find to fix this is to set fetchedResultsController to nil and then [self.tableView reloadData], which makes the FRC reload.  But this seems horribly inefficient.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, `[theTableView_A reloadData]` is the preferred and suggested way to do this.  It seems inefficient but it really is the only way to ensure that all labels, cells, headers, footers, spacing, etc is correctly laid out.

**Having said that...** there are things like:

```
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

which can deal with updating **only** sections that changed -- which may do what you need.

On the other hand, `reloadData` is massively optimized behind the scenes and caches cells and many other objects in order to not have to recalculate and redraw things it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping that was the case (that it is optimized so not as bad as it seems).